# preg_split returning whole string (unicode)

Tags: php, unicode, preg-split

I need a charAt function for utf8 strings.

If I code it like this it works, but it's too slow as it has to work on very long strings.

```
public static function utf8_charAt($str, $num)
{
    return mb_substr($str, $num, 1, 'UTF-8');
}
```

So after googling a bit I found an alternative which could be faster.

```
public static function utf8_charAt($str, $num)
{
    $split = preg_split('//u', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    return $split[$num];
}
```

Now the strange part:

On some strings the preg_split function just returns an array with the whole input string as the only item.

It looks like this while debugging:

[image: Debug screen]

The input string from the screenshot:

```
陘⊇7觬ࠒ肃⠈秀菂о 舏ꁀ車ń၀ꂀᒂƨ࠺텀脼舁㳸⁀态丌였ᯠ₀胸耉ᠷ䠠켠脳䄁︀Ȍרࠃ䰀⛠眰䀻₁ᙁƓȃ씄੖ࠖࠐ∘‘絠臱섁봂ف̘ஜနᠠ⬠㲀◁ö舄씄ֺࠊ䰐┸–䁀䢀肛脁菁±聵䄁ì섁持ũ䄀솁ā䝁ù脁龁ƴ䄁쒁상䌁䅁č脁ꒁEĀ餁K脁獁ǒ脁᳁ğ肝Ź섁䤁ųĀࣁ䄀薁Ġ脀鍁āĀ䪁Ŭ섁ꃁa섀佁Ǿ䄁㭀7©䄀鳁댁䄁}䄁굁Ǭ脀ぁĦ脀剁䄀❁Ŵ老欀沁{耀ꬁ䷁į䄀锁
```

I didn't see any coherence yet, but on some strings it works as intended. Unluckily are these the least.

Comment: Looks like it's working fine here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/79ad779630f6c6a9fb7350ab016d757e68e6f874 - except for PHP version 4.4.9, but I doubt that's your case.

Comment: `mb_substr` is MUCH faster! https://3v4l.org/9pSen

Comment: Well, I guess it was a problem with the data provider of the unit test.
But since mb_substr seems to be way faster, I don't have to struggle with preg_split. Thanks!